# Invalid property show legacy activity component error deployment

Tags: chatter, administration, page-layout, activities, flexipages

how are you? I have the following problem, I was assigned to be able to send emails from the chatter in opportunities, I created a quickAction and added it to the layout, then I went to the page builder and dragged the activities component to the chatter.

In my environment and in UAT it works fine, the problem arises when I try to deploy to production, when I am uploading the flexipage I get the following error:

`Invalid property [showLegacyActivityComposer] in component [runtime_sales_activities:activityPanel]`.

Why do I get this problem in production and not in sandboxes?

Another thing that I notice is that in production, when I drag the activities component to the chatter, it does not show me the "Use tabbed activity view" checkbox and in the other environments it does.

Comment: Maybe your sandboxes are in spring '23 and your production is not ?
What api version are you using for your deployment ?

Answer (score 3):

Your sandbox must have been in Spring 23 release and your production environment in Winter 23 release(previous release). So the metadata which you are retrieving from the sandbox is having the tags as:

showLegacyActivityComposer
false

You need to remove this part from your flexipage metadata and deploy. Thus you won't receive this error anymore.

Welcome in advance!!